# Running Oracle script from bash

Tags: oracle, bash, sqlplus

My query basically is when I am trying to run multiple oracle scripts from bash how do I put comments in between the scripts. I have tried using a workaround by selecting a string from dual. But the output formatting isn't very good.

Can anyone please suggest me a better way.

**My Code**

```
#!/bin/bash
#Run Script
    echo "-------------------------------"
    echo "***Running Script1***"
    echo "-------------------------------"
sqlplus -S UID/PSW@DB << EOF
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set echo off 
set heading off
@/my/path/Script1
Select '--------------' from dual;
select '***Running Script1***' from dual;
Select '--------------' from dual;
@/my/path/Script2
exit;
EOF
```

**Output**

```
-------------------------------
***Running Script1***
-------------------------------
SP2-0310: unable to open file "my/path/Script1.sql"

--------------


***Running Script2***    

--------------

SP2-0310: unable to open file "my/path/Script2.sql"
```

**Expected Output**

```
-------------------------------
***Running Script1***
-------------------------------
SP2-0310: unable to open file "my/path/Script1.sql"

--------------
***Running Script2***    
--------------    
SP2-0310: unable to open file "my/path/Script2.sql"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `PROMPT` command of SQL*Plus:

```
$ cat tmp.sh
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus -S UID/PSW@DB << EOF
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode
set echo off
set heading off

prompt =======================
prompt *** Running Script1 ***
prompt =======================
@/my/path/Script1

prompt =======================
prompt *** Running Script2 ***
prompt =======================
@/my/path/Script2

exit
EOF
```

Output:

```
$ ./tmp.sh
=======================
*** Running Script1 ***
=======================
SP2-0310: unable to open file "/my/path/Script1.sql"
=======================
*** Running Script2 ***
=======================
SP2-0310: unable to open file "/my/path/Script2.sql"
```

Comment: Brilliant . Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
Select '--------------' || chr(10) || '***Running Script1***' || chr(10) || '--------------' from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I've used `dbms_output.put_line` :

```
dbms_output.put_line('starting process at: '||to_char(sysdate,'HH24:MI:SS'));
```

This requires this line first, with your initial "set" statements:

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000;
```

And if you're doing stuff in a declare / begin / end block, you might want this:

```
dbms_output.enable;
```

Which may change your output.